# Java parce csv to my bean - OpenCSV

Tags: java

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;

/**
 * @author gustavo
 *
 */
public class MyBean {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "Nome")
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBean [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}




            String path = "/home/gustavo/Downloads/Relatório de uso.csv";

            Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));

             List<MyBean> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(r)
                     .withType(MyBean.class)
                     .build()
                     .parse();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;
    at com.opencsv.bean.opencsvUtils.determineMappingStrategy(opencsvUtils.java:61)
    at com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder.build(CsvToBeanBuilder.java:160)
    at billing.app.test.CreatePreviousBillingHistoryTest.readCSV(CreatePreviousBillingHistoryTest.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e explique o que você quer fazer. Não adianta copiar e colar o código e esperar que as pessoas adivinhem o propósito do mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrescente isso na sua configuração de classpath (que suponho seja o maven):

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```